# Properly reading the data of .csv files in php

Tags: php, file, csv, foreach

I have a working system on which I get the data of two .csv file. And save all the data into array and then compare some of the data existing on both csv file. The system works well but later I found out that some of the rows doesn't display on the array. I think I don't use the proper code in reading a csv file. I want to edit/improve the system. This is my code on reading or getting the data from csv file.

```
$thedata = array();

$data = file("upload/payment.csv");

   foreach ($data as $deposit){

        $depositarray = explode(",", $deposit);
        $depositlist = $depositarray;

        $key = md5($depositlist[9] . $depositlist[10]);

        $thedata[$key]['payment'] = array(
        'name' => $depositlist[0],
        'email' => $depositlist[1],
        'modeofpayment' =>$depositlist[8],
        'depositdate' => $depositlist[9],
        'depositamount' => number_format($depositlist[10],2)
    );
 }

'<pre>',print_r($thedata),'</pre>';
//more code here for comaparing of datas...
```

1.) What is wrong with `file("upload/payment.csv")` when reading csv file?

2.) What is the best code in reading a csv file that is applicable on the 
system, not changing the whole code. Should remain the foreach loop.

3.) Is `fgetcsv` much better for the existing code? What changes should be made?

Comment: i would suspect the particular lines its failing on are at issues, such as not being terminated properly. open the file in a text editor find the lines, see if there's anything odd

Comment: @Dagon, maybe some of the fields on my csv file are empty and some are having commas.

Comment: well if there are commas inside the deliminator you should be using the native csv functions and not rolling your own

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use "fgetcsv" for this purpose.
The fgetcsv() function parses a line from an open file.This function returns the CSV fields in an array on success, or FALSE on failure and EOF.
check the examples given below

eg1 :

```
<?php
$file = fopen("contacts.csv","r");
print_r(fgetcsv($file));
fclose($file);
?>
```

eg 2:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("contacts.csv","r");

while(! feof($file))
{
 print_r(fgetcsv($file));
 }

fclose($file);
?>
```

Link : https://gist.github.com/jaywilliams/385876

Comment: do you have a reference if I would like to use a foreach loop?