# Display csv file in array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have a .csv file. Some fields are empty and some fields have commas or dots.

Now how I could display it like this in array?

```
Array (

 [0] => Name1,name1@yahoo.com,13,56475,,190000,,,remit,5-Mar-15,26250

 [1] => Name2,name2@yahoo.com,11,11250,,22500,,,the bank,30-Apr-15,6250

 [2] => Name3,name3@yahoo.com,15,,,1500,receipt,,the market,7-Mar-15,1750

 [3] =>Name4,name4@yahoo.com,21,25500,,46750,receipt,,bank ,7-Mar-15,21350 ..... )
```

As of now I can only display it like this:

```
Array (

 [0] => Name1
 [1] => name1@yahoo.com
 [2] => 13
 [3] => 56475
 [4] => 
 [5] => 19000
 [6] => 
 [7] => 
 [8] => remit
 [9] => 5-Mar-15
 [10] => 26250 ) 


Array (
 [0] => Name2
 [1] => name2@yahoo.com
 [2] => 11
 [3] => 11250
 [4] => 
 [5] => 22500
 [6] => 
 [7] => 
 [8] => the bank
 [9] => 30-Apr-15
 [10] => 6250 ) ....
```

And I am using this code:

```
$file = fopen("pay.csv","r");
while(! feof($file))
{
 echo '<pre>',print_r(fgetcsv($file)),'</pre>';
}
fclose($file);
```

I prefer using native csv functions.

Comment: @Anant I will be using a foreach loop to compare all the data in array.

Comment: @Anant, Yes, I would like to use `fgetcsv` or something like that coz some of my fields are empty and have commas.

Comment: @Anant, Yes it is multi-dimensional.

Comment: Please check this link :- https://eval.in/590628  . if it is correct i will paste it as an answer.

Comment: @Anant Thanks for the effort, but not working on mine. Farkie's answer is close on what i need but the only issue on his code is some of the rows doesn't show maybe because some fields are empty and having special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's your expected output at the top you can simply use `file()` method to parse the file into an array.

```
$lines = file('file.csv');

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
 echo $line . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, How about if I have empty fields and commas?

Comment: You want to strip them? We need to see your actual expected output really.. as your expected output actually had empty fields..

Comment: I tried this before `file` but some of the rows from my csv file doesn't show in array.

Comment: Yes, and remove characters like `"` `,` or `spacing`.

Comment: @c.k i gave a link check that and let me know is it correct or you want any other modification?

Comment: @Farkie will you help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872628/properly-reading-the-data-of-csv-files-in-php

Answer (score 1):

**fgetcsv()** can solve your problem..

The fgetcsv() function parses a line from an open file, checking for CSV fields.

- The fgetcsv() function stops returning on a new line, at the
  specified length, or at EOF, whichever comes first.
- This function returns the CSV fields in an array on success, or FALSE
  on failure and EOF.

**Syntax**

fgetcsv(file,length,separator,enclosure)

- **file** Required. Specifies the file to check.
- **length** :  Specifies the maximum length of a line. Must be greater than the longest line (in characters) in the CSV file. Omitting this
  parameter (or setting it to 0) the line length is not limited, which
  is slightly slower.

Example:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("contacts.csv","r");
print_r(fgetcsv($file));
fclose($file);
?>
```

**The CSV file:**

```
Kai Jim, Refsnes, Stavanger, Norway
Hege, Refsnes, Stavanger, Norway
```

The output of the code above will be:

```
Array
(
[0] => Kai Jim
[1] => Refsnes
[2] => Stavanger
[3] => Norway
)
```

Visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php for more reference.

Answer (score 1):

Following this example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php#example-2613

```
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $filteredData = array_filter($data, function($item) {
            return '' !=== $item;
        });
        echo implode(', ', $filteredData), PHP_EOL;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

But instead of printing `implode(', ', $filteredData)`, you should remove `array_filter()` and print `implode('</span><span class="comma">', $data)` with the following CSS:

```
.comma {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
.comma:empty {
  display: none;
}
.comma + .comma {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

New PHP code:

```
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    echo '<div class="csv">';
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        echo '<div><span class="comma">';
        echo implode('</span>, <span class="comma">', $data), PHP_EOL;
        echo '</span></div>';
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

csv files are read by separating each value with comma. if you value contains a coma itself then it is treated as multiple value
example 
if you have a value B,C and a value A
if you write css as B,C,A then it treats itself as B C and A
to avoid such issue. use enclosure such as quotes or double quotes 
"B,C","A"